# Why does a known type produce a runtime error but an inferred type produces a null value?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

Let's take the following example from BigQuery, but it's the same across all other databases I've seen:

```
with tbl as (
    select [1,2,3] as arr,
    '{"IDS": [1,2,3], "Author": "Shakespeare", "Title": "Romeo & Juliet"}' as json_str,
    STRUCT('Hamlet' AS title, 'Shakespeare' AS author) as struct_val
) select
    arr[OFFSET(0)],
    struct_val.title,
    JSON_QUERY(json_str, "$.IDS[0][0].invalid")
from tbl
```

This returns:

```
1 - Hamlet - null
```

In other words, if a json access hits an invalid path, it returns `null`. However, when doing something like `struct_val.invalid_access` or `arr[OFFSET(100)]`, it will give an actual Runtime error, such as:

> Error1: Array index 100 is out of bounds (overflow) 
> Error2: Field name invalid_access does not exist in STRUCT<title STRING, author STRING>

My question is why does one form give a `null` value but the other one returns a runtime error? My thinking was it would be more consistent for them all to return `null`, but obviously people with far more knowledge than I have constructed these systems, so curious why this is so...

Comment: That doesn't look like PostgreSQL.

Comment: `JSON_QUERY(json_str, "$.IDS[0][0].invalid")` asks a correct question (regardind Sql Server syntax for example)  that is both args are correct expressions for a search function. And DB engine returns an answer, nothing is found. Compare with `substring('abc', 100, 10)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you're trying to find might be within the design documents but the actual answer is more likely to be what Serg has mentioned.

When you're doing  `arr[OFFSET(100)]`  you're telling the engine that you want to access the element that is in that position, if there's no such index, then the error appears, in other words, the engine cannot execute what is asked. In the `JSON_QUERY`, you're asking the engine to look for a value in a JSON-like string, the engine can execute what is requested, compare a json path with the string, and if nothing is found, it returns null.

This is something that gets discussed a lot outside the DB context, for example: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/228287/returning-null-or-a-empty-value-throw-exception